# How to change image in imageview when tableview cell is expand and collapse in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, imageview

I am using two images for cell, one i am showing when tableview cell is expand and the other one when cell is collapse

when cell expand i am using `arrow-bottom`

when cell is collapse `arrow-right`

for cell expand and collapse i am using below code:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! FAQTableVIewCell

    if selectedIndex == indexPath.row{
        if self.isCollapse == false{
            
            cell.arrowImage.image = UIImage(named: "arrow-rightt")

            self.isCollapse = true
        }else{
            cell.arrowImage.image = UIImage(named: "arrow-bottom")

            self.isCollapse = false
        }
    }else{
        self.isCollapse = true
    }
    self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

but the above code not working properly, first time when i expand cell its not showing bottom arrow, and if i expand two cells then also its not showing properly, pls do help with code

i need when cell expand then i need to show bottom-arrow, when cell in normal(back to its orginal position or collapsed position) then i need to show right-arrow

Answer (score 0):

When you reload rows, they get in cellForRowAt method.

You must apply changes in this method. Store collapsed indexPath and check it in method.

With array:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //use your cell identifier
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FAQTableVIewCell", for: indexPath) as! FAQTableVIewCell
    let image = collapsedCells.contains(indexPath) ? UIImage(named: "arrow-rightt") : UIImage(named: "arrow-bottom")
    
    cell.image = image
    
    //other settings
    
    return cell
}

var collapsedCells = [IndexPath]()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    //use your height values instead 44 and 120
    return collapsedCells.contains(indexPath) ? 44 : 120
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    if let index = collapsedCells.firstIndex(of: indexPath) {
        collapsedCells.remove(at: index)
    } else {
        collapsedCells.append(indexPath)
    }
        
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

Comment: with your first option cell is not expanding and collapse..

Comment: I can't understand what bool self.isCollapse make.

Did you need to collapse all rows or only rows that's equals selectedIndex?

Comment: only selected index

Comment: i have taken like this `var selectedIndex = -1`

Comment: could you update the answer for cell expand and collapse